# plot 2d irregular array in 3d

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, mayavi

I am attempting to plot 2d arrays on nonlinear surfaces in in a 3d plot. I have 2d arrays, where every column has an associated x, and y coordinate. Rows correspond to depth slices. I need to plot these 2d arrays in 3d space on a surface which has variable x and y coordinates. I have attempted using mayavi.imshow, but do not see a way to show the 2d array as an image on an irregular surface.

Example data:

```
x = np.linspace(100,120,50)
y = np.random.randint(50,60,x.shape)
z = np.arange(20)
data = np.random.rand(x.shape[0],y.shape[0])

# plot with mayavi
mlab.imshow(data)
mlab.show()
```

My goal is to be able to display this array in 3d space using the x,y,z values for each sample in my array. I am open to an plotting suggestions. originally attempted doing this in matplotlib, but was also unable to display my array on an irregular surface.

Comment: What defines your surface? Suppose the surface is `z = f(x, y)`, but I don't see how z can be produced by x and y.

Comment: Also take a look at [plotly 3D Surface Plots](https://plotly.com/python/3d-surface-plots/), which has nice browser interactive output for the user to rotate the 3D graph. Direct examples are contained within the documentation.

Comment: @BillHuang I am working with seismic data, so my array is essentially a subsurface profile, where each row corresponds to time or depth, and each column has an associated x,y position on Earth. I need to display this array in 3d space, based off of the x,y position of each column. I haven't seen plotly before, will check it out - thanks!